# Create a go back button for an iframe from its owner document

Tags: iframe, browser-history

I want to navigation in iframe history from it's owner document. I mean I have an iframe, and a button that is out of the iframe, in iframe's parent document. And I want to trigger go back for iframe with this button.

Any suggesstion?

Answer (score 0):

i would think that you would need to make a java script that sets a variable each time the iframe changes and then make a button to plug that variable in to the src